# hazelcast с помощью jmeter

Tags: jmeter

Столкнулся с задачей провести нагрузочное тестирование Hazelcast с помощью jmeter:

1. Устанавливаю соединение с hz.
2. Передаю key.
3. Получаю value.

Мне нужно узнать время между запросом и ответом. Буду признателен за помощь, если кто-то сталкивался с подобным.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Устанавливаю соединение с hz с помощью [Transaction Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-transaction-controller)
2. Передаю key.
3. Получаю value

[image: JMeter Transaction Controller]

Comment: Есть код, -  который складывает в IMap hazelcast значения. Код запускается в eclipse (соответственно в IDE есть main метод и className).Вставляю этот же код в beanShell Jmeter в Sampler result получаю это :               Response message: org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval In file: inline evaluation of: ``import java.util.logging.Level; import java.util.logging.Logger; import java.uti . . . '' Encountered "," at line 24, column 37.